# VIM - How do I assign different mappings for a key depending on whether the line is empty?

Tags: vim, macvim, keymapping

I want to assign different commands depending on context.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if line is empty:
    map x key to y command
else
    map x key to z command
```

Comment: So you want something ... if line=0 chars do THIS1, and if line/=0 chars do THIS2? Right?

Comment: Could you tell what it is you're trying to do with it? Just in case might be a better way?

Comment: @Idigas I'm trying to comment-out code or append a comment if a line is empty. (I'm using NERDCommenter)

Comment: Write a function and map that to your desired key combo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is normally achieved by `<expr>` mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> ((empty(getline('.')))?('y'):('z'))
```

As you are going to use NerdCommenter, you are forced not to use “nore”:

```
nmap <expr> empty(getline('.')) ? '' : '\cc'
```

Replace `''` with the desired code as I do not understand what you mean by “appending a comment”.

Comment: |<Leader>|cA |NERDComAppendComment|    Adds comment delimiters to the end of line and goes into insert mode between
them.

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be to have a single function whose behaviour depends on the contents of the line. Then you don't have to bother with different mappings. For example:

```
function! LineOperation()
    let curline=getline('.')
    if curline =~ '^\s*$'
        " empty line (except for whitespace): perform y command
    else
        " perform z command
    endif
endfunction
```

And then map the desired key to call this function:

```
nnoremap <silent> x :call LineOperation()<CR>
```